# How to assert that animation is running in Robolectric test

Tags: android, testing, animation, robolectric, robolectric-shadows

I want to assert that at a certain state, some view has animation running. I try to use `shadowOf(mainLooper().idleFor(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` to advance to that state when the animation takes 60 seconds to finish. But that line of code actually runs until the animation finishes. What else can I do?